# How to call a fortran function from a c++ file in node-gyp?

Tags: c++, node.js

I defined my fortran function in my "a.cpp" file as

```
extern "C" double trial_func_(long *fsize, double* fvec);
```

I compiled my fortran code with:

```
$ gfortran trial.f90 -c -o trial.o
```

I tried to build a library from the trial.o file using:

```
$ ar rcs fortranlib.a trial.o
```

My binding.gyp file:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "rocket",
      "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions"],
      "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions"],
      "libraries": [ "C:\\fortranlib.a" ],
      "sources": [
        "./cpp/a.cpp",
        "./cpp/index.cpp"
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")"
      ],
      'defines': [ 'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ],
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the following errors when I use "node-gyp rebuild":

> a.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol trial_func_ referenced in function "double __cdecl fortranTrial(void)" (?fortranTrial@@YANXZ)

> C:\fortranlib.a : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86'
> conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Any ideas how can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it.

I've been using gfortran 32-bit version, so I changed that to 64-bit.

Then I used the .o file in "libraries" instead of .a file and that worked.